# New-AzResourceLock: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: azure, locking, azure-powershell, azure-automation

When iam trying to create lock using powershell Azure automation runbook by using below script

```
New-AzResourceLock -LockName test -LockLevel CanNotDelete -ResourceGroupName rg -ResourceName resorcename -LockNotes Protection Auto created by Azure Backup -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -Force
```

error getting: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Auto'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLhMk.png) Hope you can help me with a problem trying to execute a script block, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and same error:**

**Commands:**

```
New-AzResourceLock -LockName test -LockLevel CanNotDelete -ResourceGroupName rg -ResourceName rsname -LockNotes Protection Auto created by Azure Backup -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -Force
```

Initially i have tried same command:
[image]

After I changed the Lock notes in String its worked.

**Commands:**

```
  New-AzResourceLock -LockName test -LockLevel CanNotDelete -ResourceGroupName rg -ResourceName rsname -LockNotes "Protection Auto created by Azure Backup" -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -Force
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[New-AzResourceLock (Az.Resources) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcelock?view=azps-9.1.0&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-7)

Answer (score 0):

The lockNotes parameter must be between quotes.
[image]
[image]
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcelock?view=azps-9.1.0

Try the following command

```
New-AzResourceLock -LockName test -LockLevel CanNotDelete -ResourceGroupName rg -ResourceName resorcename -LockNotes "Protection Auto created by Azure Backup" -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -Force
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should either have string variabel that contains Lock Notes or put the lock notes string in quotes,

```
$myLocknotes = "Protection Auto created by Azure Backup"
New-AzResourceLock -LockName test -LockLevel CanNotDelete -ResourceGroupName rg -ResourceName resorcename -LockNotes myLocknotes  -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -Force
```

Or

```
New-AzResourceLock -LockName test -LockLevel CanNotDelete -ResourceGroupName rg -ResourceName resorcename -LockNotes "Protection Auto created by Azure Backup" -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -Force
```